# Why Rails fails with: ruby.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-xp

I run a Rails 3 application on Windows XP and it fails sometimes with the following error:

[image]

This causes the WEBrick server to shutdown.

When I start the server again, sometimes the page loads as expected and sometimes it fails again with the same error.

I noticed that the error appears when I change one of the JavaScript files that belong to the loaded page.

What could be the reason for this ?

How could I debug this ?

My Ruby version is: `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]`.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue when I started to include images in my project. I'm also using the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your 1.9 minor version is stable. There have been some issues with unstable minor 1.9 versions of language before...

Comment: Where to check for this? I'm not able to find it on ruby's website. Do you know where will I find about this?

Comment: Well, rubyonrails.org usually has information on language-framework compatibility...

Comment: when I continuously refreshes the browser I get the error: `ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.` And 3 requests are send every time I refresh the page. I means on console `Started GET....` is printed 3 times every time I refresh the page and gets the above error in any one of the 3 requests randomly. Is it normal to have 3 requests sent every time?