# rails - ruby crashes on cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cygwin

My rails app crashes as soon as I access a web page. 
My versions of ruby and rails are:

$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.1

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i386-cygwin]

Here is the log:

[2012-02-28 09:46:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12536 port=3000

Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-28 09:46:49 +0800
Served asset /rails.png - 200 OK (29ms)
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:323: [BUG] rb_sys_fail() - errno == 0
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i386-cygwin]

-- control frame ----------
c:0010 p:---- s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 CFUNC  :write
c:0009 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 CFUNC  :<<
c:0008 p:0010 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 METHOD /home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/
rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323
c:0007 p:0260 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD /home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/
rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:295
c:0006 p:0036 s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 METHOD /home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/
rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:186
c:0005 p:0037 s:0025 b:0025 l:000024 d:000024 METHOD /home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/
rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:103
c:0004 p:0452 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/
rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:86
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:001414 d:000008 BLOCK  /home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/
rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH

### c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.
rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpser
ver.rb:86:in`run'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:103:in `send_response'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:186:in`send_body'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:295:in `send_body_string'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:323:in`_write_data'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:323:in `<<'
/home/salil.wadnerkar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpres
ponse.rb:323:in`write'

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Found the solution in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087432/ruby-crashes-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in this thread by Oscar Holmstrand:
 Workaround:

Add (or change)

config.log_level = :warn

in config/environments/development.rb

Once I set it up, then I realized that it was a problem with a gem.